# Regex : Find a number between parentheses

Tags: regex

I need a regex who find the number in bold below :

20 (L.B.D.D. hello **312312**) Potato 1651 (98)

20 (L.B.D.D. hello **312312** bunny ) Potato 1651 (98)

20 (**312312**) Potato 1651 (98)

((\d+)) find the number 98

I do not know what to do when there are other characters in the parenthesis

Comment: Would `(\([^0-9]*\d+[^0-9]*\))` work? I'm sure there's a better way of doing that though. It matches a series of digits that have any number of non-digit characters before or after it, all inside of parentheses. I think...

Comment: could you post what you've tried so far? I think that can try matching everything inside the parentheses first, then just numbers...

Comment: So you only want the first number in parentheses and ignore the number 98? What about something like:

20 (L.B.D.D. hello 312312 bunny 12345 ) Potato 1651 (98)

Should it only return 312312?

Comment: @NeilMonday 312312 or 12345  i don't care. Normaly only 1 number must be between parentheses

Comment: I think you can do with `Lookahead` and `Lookbehind` of Regular Expressions [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind). You may need to rebuild this  but do check with: `[\d,.]+(?=\))`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This only matches **312312** in the first capture group:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$
```

Regexplanation:

```
^        # Match the start of the line
.*?      # Non-greedy match anything
\(       # Upto the first opening bracket (escaped)
[^\d]*   # Match anything not a digit (zero or more)
(\d+)    # Match a digit string (one or more)
[^\d]*   # Match anything not a digit (zero or more)
\)       # Match closing bracket
.*       # Match the rest of the line
$        # Match the end of the line
```

See it [here](http://rubular.com/r/ImZaRigMv5).

Comment: what's the difference between including the `^.*` and the `.*$`, and not including them at all?

Comment: The difference is how much of the line you match, you don't need them at all `\(.*?(\d+).*\)` will do it but I like to be thorough @sampson-chen I don't know `ruby` one bit but that's my favourite `regex` demo site.. I came up with that word a couple of days ago and it goes into every `regex` answer now!

Answer (score 3):

the following regex should do it

```
@"\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\)"
```

the parenthesis represent a capturing group, and the `\(` are escaped parenthesis , which represent the actual parenthesis in your input string.

as a note:   depending on what language you impliment your regex in, you may have to escape your escape char, `\`, so be careful of that.

I'd be careful with this though, One of the textbook limitations of regex is that it can't identify properly parenthesized text.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but what does the ampersand mean here and why is the regex in quotes? What flavor of regex is this?