# Parsing a String looking characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I am trying to extract the numbers of this string: "ax(341);ay(20);az(3131);"

I think that I can do it how this:

```
var ax = data.split('(');
var ax2 = ax[1].split(')');
```

ax2[0] has "341"

Now If I can repeat this but starting in the next indexOf to take the second number.

I think that it's a bad practice, so I ask you If you have a better idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use regexp see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807207/regex-find-a-number-between-parentheses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
var str = "ax(-341);ay(20);az(3131);"
var regex = /(-?\d+)/g
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match); // ["-341", "20", "3131"]
```

Now you can just access the numbers in the array as normal.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wo0hxmq/)

Comment: Numbers can be negative, how this pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract all numbers from this.

```
var data = "ax(341);ay(20);az(3131);";
var ax = data.match(/\d+/g);
```

Here `ax` is now `["341", "20", "3131"]`

Note that `ax` contains numbers as string. To convert them to number, use following

```
ax2 = ax.map( function(x){ return parseInt(x); } )
```

EDIT: You can alternatively use `Number` as function to map in the line above. It'll look like,

```
ax2 = ax.map( Number )
```

After this `ax2` contains all the integers in the original string.

Comment: you could just say `ax2 = ax.map(parseInt)`

Comment: No. You cannot. It gives some strange result. Try out. For me it gave [341, NaN, NaN]. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint)

Comment: That will give an error because `parseInt` uses a second parameter as a radix. Better to use `Number`: `ax2 = ax.map(Number)`

Comment: @Andy ya I would have used `Number` only, but in answer `parseInt` is being used that's why I put it just like that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. `Number` seems better then `parseInt` in this case.

Comment: You should include the radix in your `parseInt`: `parseInt(x, 10);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, eg:

```
var string = 'ax(341);ay(20);az(3131);';
var pattern = /([0-9]{1,})/g;

var result = string.match(pattern);
console.log(result);
//  ["341", "20", "3131"]
```

http://regex101.com/r/zE9pS7/1