# Find everything in parenthesis not containing a number

Tags: regex

I need to do something exactly opposite to what is asked [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13807207/1469208). I need to find everything in parenthesis (including parenthesis itself and optionally including any prepending or trailing space) **not** containing *a four digit number starting with `19` or `20`* (year).

I have a large collection of audio and video files that contains some "garbage" in parenthesis, i.e.:

```
Abel the Kid - a Piece of My Love (feat. Snoop Dogg)
Alex Gaudino feat. Maxine Ashley - I'm in Love (I-039-M)
```

And I want to get rid of it:

```
Abel the Kid - a Piece of My Love
Alex Gaudino feat. Maxine Ashley - I'm in Love
```

But in the same time, I want to "save" all these entries that contains a release date (so four digit number starting with `19` or `20`:

```
56K feat. Bejay - Save a Prayer (2003)
Mariah Carey feat. Trey Lorenz - I'll Be There (2012)
Savage Garden - To the Moon and Back (1997)
```

I am a complete noob to the regular expressions, so I have come only as little as this pattern:

```
([(][^)]*[)])
```

But, it "catches" both year and "garbage" and doesn't "catch" any prepending or trailing space.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate platform/framework/language/application in which you'll be applying said regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another one - for engines that support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` could be:

```
\s*\((?:19|20)\d{2}\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|s*\([^()]+\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sZtr3F/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
\h*\((?!\h?\d{2,4}\h?\)).*\)\h*
\h*                               - match white spaces or tabs
   \(                             - match opening (
     (?!               )          - ignore the following group:
        \h?                           - optional white space
           \d{2,4}                    - 2 to 4 numbers for years like 2003 or 97
                  \h?                 - optional white space
                     \)               - closing )
                        .*\)      - match anything inside the bracket
                            \h*   - match white spaces or tabs
```

The `\h*` in the beginning and end is to remove all unwanted white spaces and tabs that are before and after the brackets.

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/xKKwVM/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use

```
\s*\((?!\d+\))[^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qmg2aH/1).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?!\d+\))` - fail the match if there are one or more digits and a `)` immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.